# Outlook (2010): Remove Category Name from Display

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I use categories as one of my sorting columns. Instead of showing just the color, it has the color and then the Category's name displayed beside it (IE: the "Color" in writing).

Is there a way to prevent the Category Name from displaying in the column?